# Facebook wall post from multiple Activities

Tags: android, facebook

I have been trying to make wall post from multiple pages but when i try to make post from other pages except original facebook page, it is giving me an exception of java.lang.NullPointerException

The method i am calling and created in a Facebook page.

```
 public void setConnection() {
    mContext = this;
    mFacebook = new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.FACEBOOK_ID_TEST));
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

}

public boolean isSession() {
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
    Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
    Log.d(TAG, access_token);

    if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
            mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
```

}

```
public void getID()
{

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fields", "birthday");
    try {
        mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         Log.e("Error in FaceBook Friends List","Exception = "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     if (isSession()) {
             Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
            try {
                mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 Log.e("Error in FaceBook Friends List","Exception = "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     } else {
             // no logged in, so relogin
             Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
             mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
     }
}
```

I am able to get the wall post dialog box but its showing "An error occurred. Please try again later".

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for you to achieve this would be to make an abstract class which extends the super class Activity, use this to hold all your facebook functions.

Then when you want to have an activity which has the facebook functionality then you would just extend this abstract class. If your not sure what I mean then take a look at the tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2), it goes through how to setup a basic Facebook Activity class. Hope this helps.